# error in msg.sender

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, contract-debugging

I'm pretty new to this solidity thing, so don't expect me to not make some elementary mistakes. 
Here's the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
  contract toss3D{
  uint tossvalue = 0;
  uint targetBlock = 0;
  bool isgameStarted = false;
  struct winningToss{
    uint256 blocksAwayFromWin;
    address winnerAddress;
  }

  function tossCoin() public payable{
    if msg.value(uint) >= 2.5 finney{

    }
}
```

}

When I try to use msg.sender, there is an error which says:

ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier

line number is 12, character number is also twelve. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis around the conditional statement. Additionally, `msg.value` is already a `uint`, so no need for what you wrote there. It should be:

```
if (msg.value >= 2.5 finney) {
```